# How to mark a multiple selection on a DataGrid control?

Tags: c#-4.0, datagrid

I've got a custom control based on a Datagrid. What I want to achieve is doing multiple selection of rows and then right click on the row selector to open a context menu.
What actually happens: Selection of multiple rows works fine until the user right clicks on the row selector. Once that is done, there is only one selected row the one over which the right mouse button was clicked.

What I need to happen: Allow the user to do a multiple selection (rows have a style for selection) and right click to open the context menu without loosing the previous selection.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just revisited the code and found that I was not updating the SelectedItems IList:

```
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
            {
                foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
                {
                    SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
                SelectedItemsList.Add(SelectedItem);
            }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't happen like that at all. Make sure that you have `DataGridView` `MultiSelect` property set to `TRUE`. Then assign your `ContextMenustrip` control to the datagrid's `ContextMenuStrip` property.

That should do the work and multiple selection should remain on right mouse click as well unless in your code behind somewhere you are altering that.

In which case, you will have to debug and find out where and how.

Comment: It is not a DataGridView, it is a DataGrid. Either way I will assume that they work in a similar fashion.